# Correction for multiple testing when testing multiple machine learning models on test set

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, multiple-comparisons

Suppose I optimize the parameters of k models on a training set (via cross-validation), and then test all of them on a separate test set. Is there some sort of correction for multiple testing that should be done here, when reporting the best result?

Comment: You seem to have a statistical test in mind already, which you haven't stated.